# WWAHost does not load XML DOM Document 6.0

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

I am migrating an existing web app to Metro UI using the Windows8 Consumer Preview, the app is using the latest datajs library datajs.1.0.3 to consume OData formatted as XML. An exception is thrown in the datajs code when calling `ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")` to get a DOM Parser. The code works fine in IE10.

Looking at the logs I can see the following error:

> Cannot load the ActiveX plug-in that has the class ID {88D96A05-F192-11D4-A65F-0040963251E5}

I understand that most ActiveX Controls are not supported, however this one is in the list of supported: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465143.aspx

Has anyone come across this before? If so, what is the solution?

Comment: Did you mean Consumer Preview?

Comment: I have a workaround, in datajs in the function createDOMParser I changed code so that window.DOMParser is returned instead of the ActiveXObject

Answer (score 0):

As the articles states, the ActiveX object you are trying to use are not supported.

You should use Windows.Data.Xml.Dom instead. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.xml.dom.aspx